# SwiftUI edges visible after using overlay

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to create rounded edges in one of my views using `overlay`.

```
.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 1)
)
```

The issue is that i still can see the edges on the background and also the stroke. How to crop the edges?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your view will not be tappable through overlay, even with transparency, so the solution is to use clip shape and background as shown below

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoRoundRectView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("DEMO")
            .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)) // clip corners
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10) // stroke border
                    .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 1)
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.orange)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    } }
```

try this.

Comment: I can not use `.fill()` because my view it's not a solid shape. I added the rest of the code but the issue is still there. @uikenan

Comment: ok you should use .cornerRadius. But If it still doesn't, you should increase the code sample.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that right now your modifiers are something like:

```
.cornerRadius(10)
.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 1)
)
```

Instead, you need to change the order of the view modifiers, as order matters! You are rounding the corners then applying a background, whereas you should be applying the background so that the corner radius can then clip that.

Try this instead:

```
.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
.cornerRadius(10)
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
        .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 1)
)
```